# Is there any section cut addon

Tags: rendering

Is there any section cut addon. In sketchup there is option we can cut the section mean time or show inner render parts.

This is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPW6EKMwmjA) of sketchup how it works and what i need. Is there any addon or how can i make a section view in Blender.

Comment: You can use a boolean modifier instead?

Comment: This could be of interest https://blendbits.blogspot.nl/2017/02/the-cutaway-shader-free-blender-add-on.html

Comment: @Patdog Thanks great addon this is a video which i found much useful for all https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-zfB8cTe2Y&feature=youtu.be